# Defining URL list for crawler, syntax issues

Tags: syntax, beautifulsoup, href, findall, urlparse

I'm currently running the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urlparse import urljoin

def hltv_match_list(max_offset):
    offset = 0
    while offset < max_offset:
        url = 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&offset=' + str(offset)
        base = "http://www.hltv.org/"
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&offset=0").content, 'html.parser')
        cont = soup.select("div.covMainBoxContent a[href*=matchid=]")
        href =  urljoin(base, (a["href"] for a in cont))
        # print([urljoin(base, a["href"]) for a in cont])
        get_hltv_match_data(href)
        offset += 50

def get_hltv_match_data(matchid_url):
    source_code = requests.get(matchid_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
    for teamid in soup.findAll("div.covSmallHeadline a[href*=teamid=]"):
        print teamid.string

hltv_match_list(5)
```

Errors:

```
  File "C:/Users/mdupo/PycharmProjects/HLTVCrawler/Crawler.py", line 12, in hltv_match_list
    href =  urljoin(base, (a["href"] for a in cont))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urlparse.py", line 261, in urljoin
    urlparse(url, bscheme, allow_fragments)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urlparse.py", line 143, in urlparse
    tuple = urlsplit(url, scheme, allow_fragments)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urlparse.py", line 182, in urlsplit
    i = url.find(':')
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'find'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I think I'm having trouble with the `href =  urljoin(base, (a["href"] for a in cont))` part as I'm trying to create a url list I can feed into `get_hltv_match_data`to then capture various items within that page. Am I going about this wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to join each href as per your commented code:

```
urls  =  [urljoin(base,a["href"]) for a in cont]
```

You are trying to join the base url to a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) i.e `(a["href"] for a in cont)` which makes no sense.

You should also be passing the url to requests or you are going to be requesting the same page over and over.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
```